# Javascript Interval not repeating

Tags: javascript, html, intervals

I have a setInterval in my HTML/Javascript document.
Now, as far as I am aware, the setInterval part is typed out exactly as it is in another document of mine, and it works perfectly there. But in this the interval is not repeating every 1 second. It runs it once, then stops. Are there any blatant errors that I am missing?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Time</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="line-one" />
<p id="line-two" />
<p id="line-three" />
<p id="line-four" />
<p id="seconds" />    

<SCRIPT type='text/JavaScript'language='JavaScript'>

var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minute = now.getMinutes();
var second = now.getSeconds();
var nIntervId;

function counter()
{   
    if (typeof(nIntervId) != "undefined") {
        clearInterval(nIntervId);
    }

    nIntervId = setInterval(changeASCII, 1000);
}

function changeASCII()
{
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = second;
    switch(second) {
        case 00:
        document.getElementById("line-one").innerHTML = " ___...___ ";
        document.getElementById("line-two").innerHTML = "|...|.|...|";
        document.getElementById("line-three").innerHTML = "|.|.|.|.|.|";
        document.getElementById("line-four").innerHTML = "|___|.|___|";
        break;
        case 01:
        document.getElementById("line-one").innerHTML = " ___   ___";
        document.getElementById("line-two").innerHTML = "|   | |_  |";
        document.getElementById("line-three").innerHTML = "| | |  _| |_";
        document.getElementById("line-four").innerHTML = "|___| |_____|";
        break;
        default:
        document.getElementById("line-one").innerHTML = "Nothing";
        document.getElementById("line-two").innerHTML = "To";
        document.getElementById("line-three").innerHTML = "See";
        document.getElementById("line-four").innerHTML = "Here";
        break;
    }
}


window.onload = counter();

</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine, although, You do not update real value of second hence You get it from date, which also is not updated.

Check this out in fiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/H8C4W/

```
function changeASCII()
{
    now=new Date();
    second=now.getSeconds();
...
```

Comment: Oh my. What a silly mistake. I really can't believe I didn't notice that. :D